# Right way to publish WinUI3 app in single .exe file

Tags: c#, .net, publish, winui-3, winexe

I have created a project in winui3, however, I just can't find a way to publish the application into a single .exe file.

- When I use the JetBrains rider to publish single .exe file, it just doesn't start.
- While, packaged application published using visual studios, doesn't start the application by clicking on .exe file but by only through visual studio.
- And in unpackaged publish, .exe file (still not single file) do runs, but most of my assets doesn't load and throws error while executing this line of code

`AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(new AppNotificationBuilder().AddText("Text").BuildNotification());`

Some requirements I have:

- After publishing, a single .exe file is generated, that I can share or upload somewhere, without any other dependencies.
- My application uses task scheduler to run itself through `Environment.ProcessPath` in another instance. So, it'll be necessary that the app runs through .exe file.
- Sending notification is optional, and I am willing to publish my app without that.

Other than this, I have seen the Microsoft's PowerToys application, and I am pretty sure that too is made in winui3, and they somehow managed to provide a single .exe on their github page.

If anyone can please help me with this, I'll be very grateful.

**TLDR: How to generate single .exe file in winui3 which runs**

Answer (score 4):

First of all, at this moment at least, you can't create a single file EXE for WinUI 3. PowerToys is not an exception and I guess you are talking about its **installer**.

What you can do is these 2 configurations. The videos are from my channel, if you are interested in.

- Make your app non-packaged (unpackaged) and self-contained. ([video](https://youtu.be/CotNgFCnoj4))
- Reduce unnecessary folders in the output folder. ([video](https://youtu.be/LHNahJi21Vg))

TLDR: Your *.csproj should have these lines:

```xml
<Project ...>
  <PropertyGroup>

    ...

    <WindowsPackageType>None</WindowsPackageType>
    <WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>true</WindowsAppSDKSelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>

  ...

  <Target Name="RemoveFoldersWithMuiFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <RemovingFiles Include="$(OutDir)*\*.mui" Exclude="$(OutDir)en-us\*.mui" />
      <RemovingFolders Include="@(RemovingFiles->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)')" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <RemoveDir Directories="@(RemovingFolders)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Everything seems to be working fine other than notifications. Is there any way to solve that issue.

Also, how an installer is created? If you have any video or resource, please link me up.

Comment: @chiraggoyal - Since you mention it, PowerToys is open source https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys, you can have a look at how it's done in https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/tree/main/installer/PowerToysSetup

Comment: You need to do a few [changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cs) when using ``AppNotifications`` on a non-packaged app.